# How to catch at compile-time an assignment of a subtype to a supertype?

Tags: typescript

I [learnt](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) that the

> rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that `x` is compatible with `y` if `y` has at least the same members as `x`

This allows an assignment of a variable of a subtype to a variable of a supertype. Is there a way to get a compile-time error regarding that assignment?

([TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20SuperT%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20field%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20an%20explicitly%20declared%20subtype%20object%20for%20a%20supertype%20variable%20generates%20an%20error%0D%0Aconst%20super1%3A%20SuperT%20%3D%20%7Bfield%3A%20'value'%2C%20extra%3A%201%7D%20%2F%2F%20compile-time%20error%3A%20Type%20'%7B%20field%3A%20string%3B%20extra%3A%20number%3B%20%7D'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'SuperT'%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20subTValue()%20%7B%20return%20%7Bfield%3A%20'value'%2C%20extra%3A%201%7D%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20super2%3A%20SuperT%20%3D%20subTValue()%20%2F%2F%20no%20compile-time%20error%2C%20BUT%20HOW%20TO%20get%20a%20compile-time%20error%20here%3F%20%0D%0A))

```js
interface SuperT {
    field: string
}

// an explicitly declared subtype object for a supertype variable generates an error
const super1: SuperT = {field: 'value', extra: 1} // compile-time error: Type '{ field: string; extra: number; }' is not assignable to type 'SuperT'

function subTValue() { return {field: 'value', extra: 1} }
const super2: SuperT = subTValue() // no compile-time error, BUT HOW TO get a compile-time error here?
```

Comment: Interesting find. I added a return type to the definition of `subTValue`, turned on all the checks, and still no error. Need to look into this! Probably there is something in the docs that define the behavior perfectly, but it is, I have to say, pretty interesting....

Comment: @jcalz, trying to find a solution, I saw you answered many typescript-related questions, even some close to mine, but not exactly the same. I hope you are reading this... :)

Comment: Looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54775790/831878). Is that it?

Comment: @awho  I'm looking 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) which aren't directly supported. You can do [various tricks with generics and conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-368244671)  to get closer.  Here's one way to do it indirectly:

```
interface SuperT {
    field: string
}

type Exactly<T, U extends T> = T & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>, never>;
const asExactlySuperT = <U extends Exactly<SuperT, U>>(superT: U) => superT;

const superOkay: SuperT = asExactlySuperT({ field: "a" }); // okay

function subTValue() { return { field: 'value', extra: 1 } }
const superBad: SuperT = asExactlySuperT(subTValue()); // error! 
// types of property "extra" are incompatible
```

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcAO0AqyDeAUMicjMBADYAmAXMgM5hSgDmhAvoYWAJ7bIAogA9EYSrwA8OADTIAqsgjDIIag2Q4AfMgC8m5ADJkAJQgIA9lGqSRCSumoRJAawi8LMBXLcev2uRAIADdoLQBuQksQJmQ4BhExCQxsKDx9SUVlVXUhUQRxKRTcOXktLQAKBixcenkASj0datScSKiLGLBGGqgAeRc4XnpitL04hPzC0ZwK-DIKGnoAIjhl5A568OQAeh3kC0Hebhh0EALgTp6AIxwANTgHCArG+agIMHQoEAIFqjpkAByYKPdAQQFybJQOD0ACMGw2HS6PVSACE4ACZuN4okCslerNqrcHk8XltdvtoFArABCZCEPbIPjYDSeZCYampPjIZZQtZxd7IUCWAC2mDgYGA10oECAA)

The idea there is that `Exactly<T, U>` will take a type `T` and a candidate type `U` which hopefully matches `T` exactly with no extra properties.  If it does, then `Exactly<T, U>` will equal `U`.  If it does not, then `Exactly<T, U>` will set the property types of any extra properties to `never`.  Since `asExactlySuperT<U>()` requires that `U extends Exactly<SuperT, U>`, the only way that can happen is if there are no extra properties in `U`.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: If for some reason the object you want to check has type `any`, no error will be raised (`const superBad: SuperT = asExactlySuperT(subTValue() as any); // no error`). Wondering if `asExactlySuperT` could deal with `any` objects, too, or if it can raise an error like "don't send me a param of type `any` as I can't deal with it".

Comment: `any` is a deliberate escape hatch from the type system. It's seen as both a supertype and a subtype of every other type (that's unsound but useful) so it will tend to allow things no matter what.  That's the point of it.  It is [possible to detect `any`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928360/2887218) and do something different with `any` than the default behavior, but be careful doing that... the expectation of `any` is that it will "just make things work", and explicitly failing on `any` might surprise people.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ray Toal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/831878/ray-toal) found out, an answer for a very similar issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54775885/5961339). (And I knew this in the first place, I just wanted to check [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)'s reaction time. Pretty impressive, @jcalz!)

Based on that approach, my code would look like:

([TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20StrictPropertyCheck%3CT%2C%20TExpected%2C%20TError%3E%20%3D%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20keyof%20TExpected%3E%20extends%20never%20%3F%20%7B%7D%20%3A%20TError%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SuperT%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20field%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doIdentity%3CT%20extends%20SuperT%3E(a%3A%20T%20%26%20StrictPropertyCheck%3CT%2C%20SuperT%2C%20%22Only%20allowed%20properties%20of%20SuperT%22%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20subTValue()%20%7B%20return%20%7B%20field%3A%20'value'%2C%20extra%3A%201%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20super3%3A%20SuperT%20%3D%20doIdentity(subTValue())%20%2F%2F%20we%20do%20get%20a%20compile-time%20error!%0D%0A))

```js
type StrictPropertyCheck<T, TExpected, TError> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof TExpected> extends never ? {} : TError

interface SuperT {
    field: string
}

function doIdentity<T extends SuperT>(a: T & StrictPropertyCheck<T, SuperT, "Only allowed properties of SuperT">) {
    return a
}


function subTValue() { return { field: 'value', extra: 1 } }

const super3: SuperT = doIdentity(subTValue()) // we do get a compile-time error!
```

Comment: @jcalz, just to be clear, it was a joke, I was sincerely looking for a solution, I wasn't aware of that answer when I posted my q :) Thanks