# typescript unable to trigger excess member check if spreading member of constrained typed

Tags: typescript

```
const abc =<T extends {res:{a:string}}>():T['res']=>{

    return {a:"1",b:1} // excess member, error as expected, ok
}

const abc2 =<T extends {res:{a:string}}>():T['res']=>{

    const c:T['res'] ={a:"1"}

    const d:T['res'] ={a:"1",b:"1"} // excess member, error as expected, ok

    return {...c,a:"1",b:1 } // no error eventhough with excess member, problem
}

const abc3 =<T extends {res:{a:string}}>():T['res']=>{

    type c = {res:{a:string}}

    const c:c['res'] ={a:"1"}

    return {...c,a:"1",b:1 } // excess member, error as expected, ok
}
```

`abc` and `abc3` work expected

however `abc2` is not what I expect

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgI2DAvAHgCowKYA8rZgAmEMA3gE7YQBcZcN0FAlmAOYC%20HAfABQCUNDAG0A5FQiiAuim5kAUPJjKYVKAFcKYcgwBEARl0AaBDX0cYAeks5cwaqQC22RwmwUjOChRAV4pPAAHbGACIk8QAGt5DkVQSFhEYAAmVExbAmJSSmo6BiZWTh4BITEJaVkFJRV46BhgUvFqaVR6GgNdWOrlWtgiRvKpVr1DE3bDC2tbewgnFzcPLx8-OADcYNDscJgoxRVVbA0tcgA6M%20AjEeNTfRhJmzAQJd8cADdCKAALEHU2T5gAO7ML7TBwwZyudyeQI%20BAAGxcMTi4DqSQAzGksHhMiRyBI8owoCx2Fw%20IIRE1JDI5HsVFAAJ7BeqoPG5NoFEldfa9eo0YBlZpDFBtDpclRqTTaMhnE4XK5jW73UGzcHzKHPFZrDZhCLRWJAA)

my question：

1. the reason `abc2` unable to trigger excess member check
2. proper way to do it

Comment: I had similar problem in Friday ) I believe it is because of spread operator, but it will be interesting to here from folks

Answer (score 1):

I would just comment but my reputation is to low, yet.

I think the example can be simplified to:

```
type ret = { a: string } 

const abc = ():ret =>{
    return {a:"1", b:"2"} // raises error as expected
}

const abc2 = ():ret =>{
    const t = {a:"1", b:"2"} 
    return t; // should raise error but doesn't
}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAThxQLxQN5QIYC4oGdgwEsA7AcygF8oAoKgYwHsi8MAjWpKACgEpM4FEAPhRUoY2PACuMIqiwAiAIzyANFBaZ5AJnmUA9HtjoCOCDigQYMejAzmIAD0i1gEACZVyNBkwTo2Whw8fPBIwqLiPswCcprKahrautTiEsDSssAA3FAGuAAW9JIANm5GJtCW1rYskghu9GZEAOTAnkA)

From my research this is an [already discussed issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) in the typescript community and due the fact that typescript is strucurally typed.

[This is a nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775790/forcing-excess-property-checking-on-variable-passed-to-typescript-function) for exactly typed function arguments, but i couldn't get it to work with return types.

Comment: the already discussed issue here is different from my case, in the issue of your link, the excess member exists inside spread object and the "parent object" unable to trigger excess member check on that spread object(which is an issue I already faced and solved). In this case, the excess member exist outside of the spread object, spreading the object causes the "parent object" unable to trigger excess member check other property.**comment repost to fix some mistake**