# Whether the type of a function parameter should not support `subtype` in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript programming, but I don't understand why a type can accept a subtype when used as a function parameter.  I think the code below should give an error but it doesn't:

```
type Numbers = { x: number, y: number };
function add(arg: Numbers) {
  return arg.x + arg.y;
}

type NumbersWithName = Numbers & { name: string }
const numbersWithName: NumbersWithName = { name: 'alice', x: 0, y: 1 };
add(numbersWithName); // No Error

const numbers: Numbers = { name: 'alice', x: 0, y: 1 }; // Error
```

If the logic in the add function does not welcome others attributes,
what should I do? Is it unreasonable to do so?

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise; `NumbersWithName` is a subtype, not a supertype.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for reminding! Has been corrected

Comment: That's just how Typescript works. It only checks for excess properties when defining object literals.

Comment: In *every* language, you can call a function with an argument whose type is a subtype of the parameter type; you can always use a subtype's value whereever its supertype's value is allowed. That is the whole point of subtypes. I don't see how there is a question here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because TypeScript has structural type system.

See next example:

```js
type Numbers = { x: number, y: number };

function add(arg: Numbers) {
    return arg.x + arg.y;
}

type NumbersWithName = Numbers & { name: string }

type Allowed = NumbersWithName extends Numbers ? true : false // true

const numbersWithName: NumbersWithName = { name: 'alice', x: 0, y: 1 };
add(numbersWithName); // no error,

// see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks
add({ name: 'alice', x: 0, y: 1 }) // error
```

You can force compiler error by using object literal instead of passing a reference to object.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775790/forcing-excess-property-checking-on-variable-passed-to-typescript-function)

See this open [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) and another one possible [workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-300613197)

Comment: This is not really to do with structural types, the issue is that OP thinks it's a supertype when really it is a subtype.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a question about Covariance_&_Contravariance.

The arguments to TypeScript function are covariant, so subtype can be used as supertype.

Read this:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)