# Union Type in function or asynchronous function is not properly calculated

Tags: node.js, typescript

### Description

I have two interfaces (`MiddlewareResponse` & `MiddlewareResponseNext`) which should be the only two possible return type for both a function or an asynchronous function (`CallbackOrPromiseCallback`).

But in the example below, TypeScript does not complain when using a wrong return type for the function.

### Question

What should I do in TypeScript to make sure that the union type as a return type of a function or an asynchronous function is correctly typed, and prevent possible typing mistakes?

### Source-code

```js
type CallbackOrPromiseCallback<Type> = (() => Promise<Type>) | (() => Type);

interface MiddlewareResponseNext {
    next: true;
}

interface MiddlewareResponse {
    next: false,
    headers: Record<string, string>;
    status: number;
    body: string;
}

interface Middleware {
    response: CallbackOrPromiseCallback<MiddlewareResponse | MiddlewareResponseNext>;
}

interface Server {
    middlewares: Array<Middleware>;
}

const server = {
    middlewares: [
        {
            response: () => ({
                next: true,
                status: 200 // Should not accept anymore properties
            })
        },
        {
            response: () => ({
                next: true, // Should be forced to false
                headers: {},
                status: 500,
                body: "Error"
            })
        }
    ]
};
```

### Playground

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYHkBOAFHAewFsBLAZwniVUwB4AVcCAPigF4oAKLgSg7YESFCI2Yt+AH258BUJpF4BuAFArSAO2AQcAM3TQAsqQAmJhBADucHBABKEcmEIbKAOQgAPYFADeKqECoDS9gAC4oYBwAVwhVAF81TW09AyhjMwtrWwcnF0o-AKCQ7wj9BEoAGiLAgAsIOBMdcgiHNEIcEzpyKM0Ac0qoHpx+llUgoeA4YGiW4OjiZB1xoORCExAI4f6EpK0dfTQjU3MrG2h-Cds81wgI6hR0bHwiMkoH2gw6DNPs+0dnLcoNIfllzrlAe5QmMVIl1PtUkcoABlHQANx0hQmZEyZ2uEQAgjgcHAQN8TmDbDC4e1XD5KDgMTgOFigjjfuc5gBtGoTVl8vnXSF3bj8dhsLiXAXSwIlcKRGIQaoymU9aazCIAJgADNqoAB6fUo2qEaIIEzBQg+dBHMDWjQgYgdaBgIiQHDAUiOXky+K8H1BeLK6VSlVQIX5EWycXcUNh4qhCJRWKDQ3G03mqBLKC6DpI4CEHOISgBsP1RrNCK+IOllVqmZzACsuuD8dW602UAARABRYkdLu1iZ+2uJCYAXVhSiAA).

Comment: I'm not sure how to get exhaustive property checks here.  It's not really an "error" to have excess properties.  Both of your return types are assignable to `MiddlewareResponseNext`.  If you add something that makes them incompatible, like `interface MiddlewareResponseNext { next: true;  headers: string; }` *then* you get the error on the second one `Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'`

Comment: I see, I was expecting it to raise an error since using one or the other interface in a standalone way like `const middleware: MiddlewareResponseNext = {next: true, status: 200}` would raise an error. I guess TypeScript has been designed that way but I was expecting it to check whether the users are mistyping their middleware response. This also means that I will have to check that at runtime. Not sure if there is another way of handling this case in TypeScript.

Comment: You can search for answers regarding excess properties.  Here’s one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54775885/10431574