# Why does TypeScript not throw an error when a variable with wrong type is passed to useState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why does the TypeScript not throw an error when a variable is passed to `useState`? Is there a way I can still type check when passing a variable?

```
type BuildingNames = [
  'farm',
  'sawmill',
];

type BuildingType = { [n in BuildingNames[number]]?: number };

interface ITownContext {
  buildings: BuildingType;
  setBuildings: (buildings: BuildingType) => void;
}

interface TownProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const defaultValues = {
  resourceBuildings: {
    farm: 1,
    asdfasdf: 5,
  },
};

const TownContext = createContext<ITownContext>({} as ITownContext);

const TownProvider = ({ children }: TownProviderProps) => {
  // no error
  const [buildings, setBuildings] =
    useState<BuildingType>(defaultValues.buildings);
  
  // error occurs
  const [buildingsDirect, setBuildingsDirect] =
    useState<BuildingType>({ asdf: 1 });

  return (
    <TownContext.Provider
      value={{
        buildings,
        setBuildings,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </TownContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { TownContext, TownProvider };
```

Comment: `defaultValues` is untyped. It may be okay, it may not, as your code is free to change it without restrictions, so it can't be statically verified. `{ asdf: 1 }` is a constant, so we know its value, and it is obviously not a `BuildingType`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference you see between the 2 usages of `useState` is the effect of TypeScript [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#suppressExcessPropertyErrors), which triggers *only* when doing an assignment of an object *literal* (i.e. as opposed to assigning the reference of another variable, like `defaultValues.buildings`).

The fact that excess property check is not enforced when assigning the reference of another variable, enables a classic OOP usage of passing a subtype (here an object with *more* properties than strictly necessary).

Still, even when excess property check does not kick in, TS still checks for other errors: should one of the properties not match its type, it will be reported.

```
const defaultValues = {
  buildings: {
    farm: "string instead of number",
    asdfasdf: 5,
  },
};

useState<BuildingType>(defaultValues.buildings) // Types of property 'farm' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
//                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJktgK4DOSAyjCjOXGlKkwMIQB2TAHvAC+cAGZQIIOACI26GFIDcAKCUwAnmCRwAQhWAAbEsG4BzQihBIqcALxwA2krhwA5CJRQQLzE9dUUAO4gBvreSgC6yqoaWroGRqYAKjG2uA7ccMY6eobGZhZW9twUIABGSFDh4QD8AFxwxWUVcIJRxkxQ7mhaAJKJEAHcXLxIAri+pTkJJlT1cblJMcrONDDz07NwABST8Xmb63nJmgCUtgB8cABuEMAkyoIq7RVdWv2DAAriV3cVXxBgaw4XxoAAW8TY3HqyDkxDIDxUaB4VHgZHcFH0MAAaih9BQrKlgc5dgsZvUic5RB4QPUpFIfJS4CgqCR3CyRPUAKwMlo+VqI5Hwd5DHj8eB2VjsJDDMUAHj6AxFIwE5y2OGEzLgCsGMtGMBOUSR3BRcGF-x+ZCgqTVLHBhkhLXqZu+vyg-0BZxslwpAHofQ0IHAKuIoCDBQ4SRtsKtDqYqOFbL5nNQ6AwmLLYyZjkhVWiUBjsbj8VQAHSR-YG3y+P1BqAhuAQNBoChQKhh43wezluMAEWAbAw0aQaym+z7A5gCZsSbgKfojCQGdHi00qrwzNZ9QAjC1K742DAWxktjPZcLdQIS+bXTPnFci0gbDgKYzicuZjzX3AY++qJ-KYIjyMuct64GCEJINwQGUrKPrnqKepXi6logc4lb8koQA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So there is no way to check if an object with an unknown property is passed to `useState` with this pattern? Do you know of another way?

Comment: There are some workarounds  see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775790/forcing-excess-property-checking-on-variable-passed-to-typescript-function